# How to encode Object to Json in flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, serialization, http-post

I have a Subject object

```
class Subject {
  String subjectName;
  int pages;
  int fullMarks;

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> toJson() async {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'pages': pages,
      'fullMarks': fullMarks,
    }
  }
}
```

and student object

```
class Student {
  String name;
  int rank;
  Subject sub;

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> toJson() async {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'rank': rank,
      'subject': sub.toJson(),
    }
  }
}
```

i want to send this student object in POST request.

i did: here student is object of Student class.

```
var data = jsonEncode(await student.toJson());
```

but in data Subject value is null.
Does anyone knows why??

Comment: have you tried to debug the code and check if `student.sub` is not-null?

Comment: yes , Object of Subject is not null, i debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `await` before `sub.toJson()` as

```
'subject': await sub.toJson()
```

`await` will allow the future to complete while waiting for the result, otherwise a future object will be returned immediately, which is not desired.

Comment: or even better, do not make `toJson()` functions `async`, there's no need to

Comment: @mfkw1 thanks that worked too, i am new to dart and flutter , so a bit confused about async and await.